# CHECK an attribut of a class/object in a list

Tags: python

```
import nxppy
import time

class student: # Object giving first and last name, idCard and statut
    def __init__(self, name, idCard, present):
        self.name = name
        self.idCard = idCard
        self.present = None

class_TS4 = []
class_TS4.append(student('moureton etienne', '4DC3A150', None))
class_TS4.append(student('metzinger axel', '5FG998H2', None))
# print(class_1S4)

# Instantiate reader
mifare = nxppy.Mifare()

while True:
    try:
        uid = mifare.select()
        for student in class_TS4:
            # comparing uid to the each of the student's idCard attribute
            if uid == student.idCard:
                 student.present = True
                 print(student.present)
                 print(student.name)
                 break  # since uids are unique there is no point to check other students

    # Permet le polling
    except nxppy.SelectError:
        pass

        time.sleep(1)
```

Hello world !I need your help as quik as possible... I work on a project at Hihg School and i'm blocked. I begin in **Python** and am programming on a Pi3 B+ running Raspbian.

I have to read the **UID of some NFC** card and this is working without problems. But I have to check if the UID i read match with the **"self.idCard"** one of my class. If yes, i want to change the **"self.present"** of the object containing the UID to True.

At least, the goal is that i add 30 "students" like those one and that the program can tell me which one passed his card.

The idCard's UID is unique and constant for each student.

Thanks all <3

Answer (score 2):

You currently compare the read `uid` to an instance of your class, which will always be `False`. You should compare apples to apples:

```
while True:
    uid = mifare.select()
    for student in class_TS4:
        # comparing uid to each of the student's idCard attribute
        if uid == student.idCard:
             student.present = True
             break  # since uids are unique there is no point to check other students
```

Another, more efficient approach would be to use a dictionary. This way uid lookup will be `O(1)`:

```
uids_to_student = {student.idCard: student for student in class_TS4}

while True:
    # Read UID data
    uid = mifare.select()
    try:
        uids_to_student[uid].present = True
    except KeyError:
        print('No student with this UID exist in class')
```

BTW, `student.__init__` accepts a `present` argument but does not do anything with it. Either remove it from the signature, use it or give it a default value:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, idCard, present=None):
        self.name = name
        self.idCard = idCard
        self.present = present
```

Comment: Hi men ! Thanks a lot, that help ! A problem is still here... As i added 2 students, i was excpected that if the second student passed his card, it worked but nop... Mine is passing but nop my friend's one (the second student i added).

Comment: @Etienne: That's because a `KeyError` occurs anytime an attempt is made to access a `uid` that's never been seen. When using the `try/except` approach, you need to distinguish between it happening because an invalid `uid` was given verses when you're trying to add a new one.

Comment: @martineau Okay bro', have add a KeyError under the try but not working too... What should i add exactly ? I could forgot something as I begin ^

Comment: @Etienne: Sorry, but you sound like maybe you're a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).